# How to catch an event coming from database to C# (chat application)

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm trying to develop chat application software using visual C# and Firebird as the database.

When a client a sends a message, I want client B to be notified.

How could I notify client B from the database that a message is waiting?

Assuming that I created an event table in my database that when an insert is made to the message table, how would I catch the message generated by the database in C#?

Can somebody guide me what code I should use in C# just to catch the notification of the database and display it to client B?

Comment: this task is more suited to a messaging queue than a database; you can save the logs from the chat into the database for archiving if you wish, but monitoring the database for inserts isn't practical.  Try SignalR, or RabbitMQ.

Comment: oh ok. I'll try your suggestion. hopefully I can understand

Comment: @Claies Firebird has events that can be posted (for example in a after insert trigger), which clients can subscribe to (which then needs to check the database for the actual data). Although I agree that for a chat application that probably isn't ideal.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well I'm trying to implement it that way although my dilemma is how would c# catch the event thrown by the firebird. I'm trying to study other concepts on how would I implement the Chat application. Do you have an idea how to catch the event of firebird on c# or on other language?

Comment: The Firebird .net provider has an event manager which you can use to subscribe and get notified. I don't have the exact details available right now. In Java it is the FBEventManager class.

Comment: @markrotteveel by the way sir I've been trying what you post but couldn't make it to success. Do i need to create a firebird trigger on the database side. Can you give me an example of trigger after the "insert or update" in the database? Information on beginners like me seems to be so scarce

Comment: My example is self-contained: you only need to connect to an existing database. For more details on creating triggers, look at the Interbase 6 Data Definition Guide, chapter 10 (working with triggers) combined with the information in the Firebird 2.5 language reference update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a very simple program that handles events, it was copied/modified from [Firebird .NET - Examples of use](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/#firebird_events).

The class that handles the events is `FbRemoteEvent`. You register the event(s) you are interested in on an instance and you add event handler(s) to be notified when an event occurs. Events are notified asynchronously (although the example doesn't clearly demonstrate that). The event count is the number of events since the last (processed) event notification.

To simplify the example I have used an execute block to directly post the event (instead of - for example - posting the event from a trigger). Note that in this example the connection notifies itself of the event, but it would have worked exactly the same if the notification was coming from a different connection:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
        cs.DataSource = "localhost";
        cs.Database = @"TESTDATABASE.FDB";
        cs.UserID = "SYSDBA";
        cs.Password = "masterkey";
        cs.Charset = "NONE";
        cs.Pooling = false;

        FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(cs.ToString());
        connection.Open();

        FbRemoteEvent revent = new FbRemoteEvent(connection);
        revent.AddEvents(new string[] { "new_order" });

        // Add callback to the Firebird events
        revent.RemoteEventCounts += new FbRemoteEventEventHandler(EventCounts);

        // Queue events
        revent.QueueEvents();

        string sql = "EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN POST_EVENT 'new_order'; END";

        FbCommand command = new FbCommand(sql, connection);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        connection.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void EventCounts(object sender, FbRemoteEventEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event {0} has {1} counts.", args.Name, args.Counts);
    }
}
```

Comment: this might become useful. I'll try it right away. Do you have a link for firebird tutorial like HELLO world. I mean useful examples in coding events and triggers. I'm kinda beginner in Firebird programming. thx...

Comment: You can look at the Interbase 6 documentation that you can download from the Firebird website. It also contains simple examples (iirc in the language references).

Comment: Can you show me the direct link especially on the Interbase 6 documentation since google always redirects me on firebirdsql.org and couldn't find what I am looking for. thx

Comment: That is because it is hosted on firebirdsql.org, see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ near the end of the page.

Comment: atleast I know now where to start reading. Will start reading right away. It's really helpful thanks